# Symbol not found - linking to hdf library

Tags: linker, hdf

I am trying to use the hdf5-format to store data. Problem is, that I fail to link against the library. I have the following code

```
#include <H5Cpp.h>
int main(void){
    H5::H5File file("test_MatrixRoundTrip_Double.h5", H5F_ACC_TRUNC);
}
```

and compile it using

```
gcc -std=c++11 -o main main.cpp -I /usr/local/include/ -L /usr/local/lib/ -lhdf5 -lhdf5_hl
```

This always returns the error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "H5::FileAccPropList::DEFAULT", referenced from:
  _main in main-c207d1.o
  "H5::FileCreatPropList::DEFAULT", referenced from:
  _main in main-c207d1.o
  "H5::H5File::H5File(char const*, unsigned int, H5::FileCreatPropList const&, H5::FileAccPropList const&)", referenced from:
  _main in main-c207d1.o
  "H5::H5File::~H5File()", referenced from:
  _main in main-c207d1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I installed the hdf5 library on OSX using

```
brew install homebrew/science/hdf5
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you compile with gcc? Have you tried using g++ instead?

Comment: g++ yields the same errors. I used the following command `g++ -std=c++11 -o main main.cpp -I /usr/local/include/ -L /usr/local/lib/ -lhdf5 -lhdf5_hl`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are including the HDF5 C++ header file, but only linking the HDF5 C library. Add the line: `-lhdf5_cpp` to link the C++ shared object and use `locate libhdf5_cpp` to find it's libpath.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Can you explain this in more detail :)? fyi: My hdf files are in the location '/usr/local/lib'.

Comment: @VivekBagaria: I would suggest not using the C++ bindings to HDF5, just use the C bindings. The C++ bindings are not maintained very well.